# Does Shimano XTR RD-M9000 SGS 11-Speed Shadow+ MTB Rear Derailleur Long Cage work with 10speed XT shifter?

Tags: derailleur, shifter, cassette

I just bought a used bike with a broken 10 speed XT rear derailleur. Would a NEW Shimano XTR RD-M9000 SGS 11-Speed Shadow+ MTB Rear Derailleur Long Cage
( 182006158222 ) be compatible with 10 speed XT shifter & 10 speed Shimano XTR 11-36t Titanium Cassette that I have?

Comment: What ever your decision verify if the replacement will fit your hanger there are direct mount and conventional mount types.

Comment: Thank you for your input, the frame has a conventional mount & compatible with the derailleur. My main concern is, with the derailleur move based on the shifter actuations or is it preset? I am just worried of derailing each time I shift.

Answer (score 3):

I can say from experience this does not work well at all.

Although as mentioned above the chain does run through the shifting is dreadful. I tried it with a 10 speed shifter but gears would always have a spot where they would jump.

Just get a 10 speed rear derailleur.  You will be glad you did.

Answer (score -1):

Will it work?  Probably.  The range of movement of the mech wont be an issue and the chain will run through it, so I cant see why it wouldnt work.  This article is quite helpful:
http://velonews.competitor.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722

Shimano will tell you 11spd components wont work with 10spd though.  If I were you I'd just get a 10spd rear mech.

Answer (score -1):

I can say for experience this does work perfectly (I used SLX 10s shifters + XTR M9000 SGS 11s rear derailleur + XT M771 10s cassete (with a 42t cog) + SRAM X01 11s chain).
In the video below you can check a Shimano Zee 10s shifter working perfect with a Shimano XT M8000 11s rear derailleur.

Another report that it works perfectly:

http://forums.mtbr.com/drivetrain-shifters-derailleurs-cranks/xtr-rd-m9000-works-10-speed-drivetrain-947611.html

Comment: Hi Marcelo. I see you haven't taken the [tour]. It's useful.